# Upload a file into a VB.NET application running under terminal services

Tags: vb.net, rdp, terminal-services

We are developing an application in VB.NET that will need to accomodate remote users logging onto a Microsoft Terminal Server using RDP through the MSTSC.exe client.

Is it possible to offer an 'Upload' button which will allow the remote user to pick a file from his/her local hard drive and upload to the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Windows Remote Desktop client, each user will have to enable an option.  Under **Local Resources**, press **More...**.  Here you can select the local drives you want the Terminal Server to see.  The drives will come up as a network drive on the Terminal Server.

I don't know if you need to set up anything on the Terminal Server.  You may need to open additional ports on the firewall.